# check the checkbox if exists if not refresh in iMacros

Tags: java, javascript, loops, if-statement, imacros

I am trying to make a script for page, all I need is just simple java script, if there is a text on the page in example - *no found* the macros should hit the button *find work*. The macros must hit the button *find work* in 1 second interval.
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how you could make JavaScript script for iMacros. The main part is `CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER` since that part hovers over a page element. If element is present it will return true else it will return false. Try it out.

```
var macroTest;

macroTest ="CODE:";
macroTest +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:TestForm ATTR=NAME:C9&&VALUE:ON CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";

if(iimPlay(macroTest)>0)
{
alert("Checkbox found");
}
else
{
alert("Checkbox not found");
}
```